# Cassandra set datatype as uniqueness counter

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm going to use cassandra set column type to implement some counters that track unique page hits. So there is going to be a lot elements per set which wouldn't be deleted.

I don't need to retrieve the actual elements, but need to track uniqueness.
Also I need the ability to get the set size. Do we have some native mechanism for such operation or UDF is an only way?

Does the set is a good chose for this scenario at all?

Comment: set for large amount of data, probably antipattern. 

to cite https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/types.html

Please note that while some of those limitations may or may not be removed/improved upon in the future, it is a anti-pattern to use a (single) collection to store large amounts of data.

but definition of large is very subjective, probably in the magnitude of 10M?

think you should really consider counter data type.